# How can I disable the autocomplete function in Jupyter notebook(Tab)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I typed "Summary" outside the cell and change the config of Jupyter notebook.
When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the autocomplete menu pop out, but I only want 4 spaces when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I Google this question and try something like:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=False
```

However, I still have the autocomplete menu when I press Tab. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension called 'Hinterland' for jupyter, which automatically displays the drop down menu when typing or control when it should appears . There are also some other useful extensions.

In order to install extensions, you can follow the guide on this [Github repository](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) . To easily activate extensions, you may want to use the [extensions configurator](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator).

To install Hinterland run in a `Conda` terminal this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
```

To enable it :

```
jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland
```