# How can I disable tab complete in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a complex data structure, with essentially a tree-like structure, that takes a while (minutes) to load (it has to scan the filesystem and look for changes to lots files). I want to interrogate this structure, with a top-level variable called `obj`, in IPython. When I do so, muscle memory often kicks in, and I hit `obj.<tab>` which triggers a tab complete. This seemingly forces a reload of the entire structure (rescanning the filesystem), which again takes minutes. I would like to disable this - how can I do this?

Ideally, the solution would involve changing the IPython settings within the session. It would also be acceptable to modify the code that builds the structure (I have control over this).

I have previously noticed similar behaviour with `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696282/how-can-i-disable-the-autocomplete-function-in-jupyter-notebooktab